# Tutorials play very slowly, what can I do?

Tags: performance, deus-ex-human-revolution

My machine can handle Deus Ex Human Revolution fine with the resolution turned down a bit from my screen's native resolution. However tutorial clips and cutscenes play extremely slowly - the audio is very choppy and basically unintelligible. Is there a setting I can change that's likely to improve things, or should I just tab out and look them up on YouTube instead? This is on an i5 CPU.

Comment: AMD/Intel cpu? AMD/nVidia gpu? Huge thread on cutscene performance (same thing) here -> http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=119684, has about 20 different answers in it to test, I will see if I can find you something definitive!

Comment: Apparently this issue should affect all Steampowered games under the provision you're using an AMD cpu and [requires a BIOS update to fix](http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?276698-A-fix-for-Valve-CEG-games-causing-BSOD-on-Bulldozer-issue&p=5005608&viewfull=1#post5005608), obviously completely invalid if you're on Intel hardware though...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried watching the tutorials from the Main Menu when you start the game? I think those will play fine from the menu.

Comment: I have the same trouble as fredley, and I tried playing the tutorials from the opening menu. The audio skipping was actually worse than when I watched them during the game.

Comment: @Fambida Yup, just checked and it sounds like exactly the same thing.